# Ad Hoc distribution with Wildcard provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, adhoc

I'm trying to code sign on of my apps with a Wildcard app ID and provision profile. The problem is every time I archive it and try to export it through Ad Hoc I get the following error message:

No matching provisioning profiles found for "Application/The App.app"
None of the valid provisioning profile include the devices:
My iPhone, etc...

On top of that when I go back into the build settings the distribution profile setting keeps switching back to some long alphanumerical string. Any advice (I'm using Xcode 6 by the way)?

Comment: It sounds like you're launching Xcode as a user with insufficient permissions. Can you try launching from the command line: `open /Applications/Xcode.app` to see if it helps? Also, do an `ls -l` on your source code directory to make sure the files are owned by your user account.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem,

Make sure your Code Signing Identity is correct, The Code Signing Identity I had chosen was not the correct one, I had a Developer identity selected for a distribution selection.

Also you need to be using a distribution Code Signing identity and profile for ad hock distribution and not a debug.